# Having issues with the Scanner again

Tags: java, class, oop, methods, bluej

I'm having a hard time trying to use the Scanner in Java.

I tried my best to find the error of this code but I couldn't find it.

I run it then the program allows me to choose one "code" and the "word" and "category" (if the code is d). When I try to enter another code the program enter an infinite loop. Could you guys please point out where my error might be?

```
import java.util.*;
public class GrammarChecker {       
  public static void main(String [ ] args) 
  {
   Dicionary dicionary = new Dicionary();
   Grammar grammar = new Grammar();
   Item a;
   String word, category, specification;
   int count = 0;
   char code;
   Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in); 
   System.out.println("What is the code?");
   code = entry.nextLine().charAt(0);                 
   switch(code)
   {
      case 'd':
          System.out.println ("How many words your dicionary will have");
          count = entry.nextInt();
          entry.nextLine(); 
          for(int i = 0; i < count; count--) 
          {
            System.out.println ("What is the word?");
            word = entry.nextLine();
            System.out.println ("What is the category?");
            category = entry.nextLine(); 
            a = new Item (word, category);
            dicionary.listWords(a);

          }
      break;

      case 'g':   
         System.out.println ("How many lines are you going to use to specify your grammar?");
         count = entry.nextInt();
         entry.nextLine();

         for(int j = 0; j < count; count--) 
         {
          System.out.println ("What is the specification?");
          specification = entry.nextLine(); 
          grammar.listStructure(specification);

         } 

      break;

      case 'c':
          System.out.println ("I only accept d ou g");
      break;

      case 'f':
            System.out.println ("I only accept d ou g");
      break;
    }

    System.out.println("Would you like to enter another code?");
    code = entry.nextLine().charAt(0);
    entry.nextLine();

  }  
}
```

Comment: is it Dicionary? or a typo? :)

Comment: It's a Brazilian classwork so it is in portuguese. I just translated the words literally from portuguese.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a loop in your code to read multiple lines. So it seems to get stuck at `entry.nextLine();` at the end. Also you are assigning a new value to `code` that is never used. Try something like this :

```
loop: while (entry.hasNextLine()) {
    code = entry.nextLine().charAt(0);
    switch (code) {
        // handle each case except 'e'
    case 'e':
        break loop;
    }
    System.out.println("Would you like to enter another code?");
    System.out.println("Otherwise press e");
}
```

Comment: Thank for the quick reply! I have never used labels in Java before.

Comment: They are useful for breaking nested loops or switches nested in loops. You could also add an if statement after the switch and print a message for example

Answer (score 0):

When you do `entry.nextLine()`, it tries to read another value it seems. I had to enter twice a character to make the program end.

```
run:
What is the code?
e
Would you like to enter another code?
a
a
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

(This was tested in Netbeans)
But as @Manos said, if you want to continue to ask you need to make a loop around all your code.